# Excluding an unmodified field when executing SaveChanges

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

An issue occurs when I want to save an object posted back from a form, but exclude a particular field from the resultant SQL statement. In this case I did not want to include the password field in a user edit form.

An edit HttpPost controller method contained this:

```
db.Users.Attach(user);
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Password).IsModified = false;
db.SaveChanges();
```

I assumed that the .IsModified statement would mean that the generated SQL would consist of an UPDATE statement without the password field and so not overwrite the existing password value with null in the database.

However, this was not the case and EF seems to work in a slightly different way. My user class and its associate metadata class did not specify that the password field was required and yet, when executing, there was a ‘Password field required’ DbEntityValidationException thrown when SaveChanges was invoked.

One solution would be to include the password field with its value as a hidden form field, which would suffice in most cases, but in this instance would not be a good idea as password, hashed or otherwise is rather sensitive data.

On further inspection, it seemed that, in this case where we are using a database first approach, the .edmx file contains a ‘not null’ directive on the Password field. When EF comes to execute the actual save, this is checked and the exception raised.

This was not entirely intuitive in my opinion but once it is known it can be worked around.

My solution was to provide a value for the excluded field and retain the .IsModified statement. This means the DbEntityValidationException isn’t thrown as EF sees the Password field containing a value (as prescribed in the .edmx file) but is not actually written to the database due to IsModified being false. E.g.

```
user.Password = "not required";
db.Users.Attach(user);
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Password).IsModified = false;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a better solution to this as using a dummy value as above seems like a bit of a hack?

Comment: Have you thought about using ViewModels and reducing the amount of unneeded data you are moving around?

Comment: We normally use the viewmodel approach but in this case we have made a decision to expose our db models to the presentation layer so we can fully use the scaffolding/templating features in vs2015, while using a db first approach. The benefit of this has been to remove all the viewmodel and mapping related code (automapper etc) which has been great in simplifying our code. We've had trouble in the past with business logic being placed in viewmodel mappings. The trade off is that we have to enforce strict control over db changes/rescaffolding as we are conscious of introducing tight coupling.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really explained why you don't want to save the password field, I'm assuming its just because you don't know what the value is and in your current code it is being set to NULL.

You could use a ViewModel to bind with your webpage, and only supply the fields that are required (so in your case, NOT the password field).  When the user POSTs data back, you can load the user from the db, set only the fields you need to, then save the data back.  The password field will be unchanged.

For example, assuming the User table is this:

```
ID
UserName
Password
FullName
```

You would have a view model class of

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

When the data is posted back to the server from the client:

```
using (MyEntity db = new MyEntity())
{
    User u = db.Users.Find(userViewModel.ID);
    u.UserName = userViewModel.UserName;
    u.FullName = userViewModel.FullName;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: We normally use the viewmodel approach but in this case we have made a decision to expose our db models to the presentation layer so we can fully use the scaffolding/templating features in vs2015, while using a db first approach. The benefit of this has been to remove all the viewmodel and mapping related code (automapper etc) which has been great in simplifying our code. We've had trouble in the past with business logic being placed in viewmodel mappings. The trade off is that we have to enforce strict control over db changes/rescaffolding as we are conscious of introducing tight coupling.

Answer (score 0):

GO with the stored procedure approach, where you dont need to worry about entity framework, call stored proc from entity framework and update your table inside sql statement without updating password field